# How to apply SVG filter(s) to create a colored SVG form of the whole silhouette?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have an image in pgn, e.g. chess piece (white king)

[image: Image of white King]

Is there a simple way of applying SVG filters with this image to obtain an SVG containing the same shape (sillhouette( outline) and being filled with one color (e.g. red)?

Comment: not really. How would the filter distinguish between the internal and external parts of the chess piece.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to remove the outer area of the piece because it’s transparent and then draw a red rectangle clipped by the resulting shape

Comment: Or assuming this image is consisting of three areas: transparent on the outside, black „stroke“ on the outline and white inside. Then I might convert the non transparent area to a path. Or I might apply feColorMatrix to map the black color to red and then something else.

Comment: Or just draw it in SVG in the first place, then you can colour it as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where your image has a white fill and a transparent outside, then yes, you can do this with an SVG filter.

```css
img {
  filter: url(#colorise);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Fill the filter area with red -->
      <feFlood flood-color="red" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Trim the red to just what's "in" (inside) the image (ie non-transparent) -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <!-- Multiply the trimmed red shape with the original image. Black parts stay black. White parts become red. -->
      <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
```

**Update**

How to make the whole thing red, including the black parts.

```css
img {
  filter: url(#colorise);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Fill the filter area with red -->
      <feFlood flood-color="red" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Trim the red to just what's "in" (inside) the image (ie non-transparent) -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceAlpha"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
```

Comment: That‘s great and really helpful! I will accept this answer but kindly ask you to clarify one thing. Can‘t I apply a similar operation as a second step to also turn the black color into red ? Or what is the reason to distinguish the raster image parts which are not transparent ?

Comment: It's actually easier to do that.  It just wasn't clear that that was what you wanted.  I've updated my answer.